# Country Flags are incorrectly shown in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to display the flags for each country. But it seems most of the flags are incorrect according to my code. I want them to be displayed only at the end of the geom line, add the flag to the legend, and make the flag more visible than how it displays now.

```
categ_top10EnergyModf %>%
mutate(country = tolower(country)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x= year, y=ggwt_hours, country = country, color=country, group=country))+
  geom_line(size=1.5)+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_flag(aes(country = factor(country), size = 4))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  facet_wrap(~type2,scale='free')+
  labs(x= "Year", y= "Energy Production (GWh)", title = "Analysis of the Growth of Renewable/Non-Renewable Energy Production",
       color="Country",fill = "country" )+
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Country", 
                       labels= c("Germany", 
                                 "Spain", 
                                 "France", 
                                 "Italy", 
                                 "Norway", 
                                 "Poland", 
                                 "Sweden", 
                                 "Turkey", 
                                 "Ukraine", 
                                 "United Kingdom")
                       )+
  theme_grey() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

> dput(head(categ_top10EnergyModf))
structure(list(country = c("de", "de", "fr", "fr", "fr", "de"
), country_name = c("Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"France", "Germany"), type2 = c("Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", 
"Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable", "Non-Renewable"
), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2016", 
"2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), ggwt_hours = c(471984, 449906, 
448690.614, 447109.694, 445175.494, 393234.585)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(country = c("de", "de", "de", "fr", 
"fr", "fr"), country_name = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"France", "France", "France"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2016", "2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could display a flag as the last point:

```
geom_flag(aes(x = ifelse(year == 2018, year, NA)), size = 4)
```

I also set the `size` not as an aesthetic.
You dont have to use `factor(country)`. You defined your country aesthetic in `ggplot` already.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you so much for the answer. I tried it but getting this error. Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘grobify’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 40 rows containing missing values (geom_flag).

Comment: Cannot say where xour error comes from. The warnings can be ignored though.